# How to use Azure Map Popup in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-maps

How can I use Azure Map's Popup in Angular? I tried the following code but it gives an error on the getProperties.
Error:
Property 'getProperties' does not exist on type 'Feature<Geometry, any> | Shape'.
Property 'getProperties' does not exist on type 'Feature<Geometry, any>'.

```
this.map.events.add('ready', ()=>{
  this.dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
this.map.sources.add(this.dataSource);
this.dataSource.add(new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point([-118.243683, 34.052235]),{
  name: 'Microsoft Building 41', 
  description: '15571 NE 31st St, Redmond, WA 98052'
}))
this.layer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(this.dataSource);
this.map.layers.add(this.layer);
this.popup = new atlas.Popup({
  pixelOffset: [0, -18],
  closeButton: false
});

this.map.events.add('mouseover', this.layer, (e)=>{
  if (e.shapes && e.shapes.length > 0) {
    var coordinate;
    this.properties = e.shapes[0].getProperties();
    this.content = this.popupTemplate.replace(/{name}/g, properties.name).replace(/{description}/g, properties.description);
    coordinate = e.shapes[0].getCoordinates();

    this.popup.setOptions({
      //Update the content of the popup.
      content: this.content,

      //Update the popup's position with the symbol's coordinate.
      position: coordinate

    });
    //Open the popup.
    this.popup.open(this.map);
  }  
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects in the events shapes array can be `atlas.Shape` objects or GeoJSON Features. Clusters and data that are in vector tile sources will be Features, in a DataSource will be `atlas.Shape` objects. To consistently get the properties and coordinates consistently you can do the following.

```
var s = e.shapes[0];
var props = (s instanceof atlas.Shape) ? s.getProperties : s.properties;
var coordinates =  (s instanceof atlas.Shape) ? s.getCoordinates(): s.geometry.coordinates;
```